# Scrapy to S3 Bucket: missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get scrapy to write results to an S3 bucket.  I have the following in my config file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 1
}
FEED_URI = 's3://1001-results-bucket/results.json'
FEED_FORMAT = 'json'
```

My parse function is incredibly simple:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        for n in range(0,1):
            request = scrapy.FormRequest("https://website", formdata={'id': "%s" % i})
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'foo': 'bar'
        }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
  self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
  return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 40, in from_settings
  mw = mwcls()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 updated with class definition

Comment: could you show the codes in middleware.py?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by creating a custom pipeline, which seems to work fine.

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'test.pipelines.S3FileUpload': 1
}
```

pipelines.py

```
import boto
import boto.s3
from boto.s3.key import Key
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import Dotenv
dotenv = Dotenv(join(dirname(__file__), ".env"))
os.environ.update(dotenv)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

class S3FileUpload(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        bucket = s3.get_bucket('my-bucket')
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = 'test.json'
        k.set_contents_from_string(str(item))
        return item
```